# I setup three rabbitmq queues with spring cloud, one of the queues randomly fails

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

What I am trying to do is, When I receive a message at consumer, I filter that message based on there content the filter will send messages to 3 different queues with the help of three different producers.

> **this is the configuration for three queues :**

```
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        QuickScore:
          concurrency: 5
          destination: quickScore
          content-type: application/json
          group: quickScoreGroup
          maxConcurrency: 10
          recoveryInterval: 10000
        SuitabilityScore:
          concurrency: 5
          destination: suitabilityScore
          content-type: application/json
          group: suitabilityScore
          maxConcurrency: 10
          recoveryInterval: 10000
        CompletenessScore:
          concurrency: 5
          destination: completenessScore
          content-type: application/json
          group: completenessScore
          maxConcurrency: 10
          recoveryInterval: 10000

  rabbitmq:
    host: ${rabbitmq.host:localhost}
    username: guest
    password: guest
    port: 5672
```

> Custom channel for queues

```
public interface CustomChannels {

  @Output("QuickScore")
  MessageChannel publishMessageToQuickScore();

  @Input("QuickScore")
  SubscribableChannel receivedAtQuickScore();

  @Output("CompletenessScore")
  MessageChannel publishMessageToCompletenessScore();

  @Input("CompletenessScore")
  SubscribableChannel receivedAtCompletenessScore();

  @Output("SuitabilityScore")
  MessageChannel publishMessageToSuitabilityScore();

  @Input("SuitabilityScore")
  SubscribableChannel receivedAtSuitabilityScore();
}
```

> producers for queues :

```
@Autowired
  private CustomChannels customChannels;

  public void sendToQuickScore(UpdatedFieldsEntity updatedFieldsEntity) {
    customChannels
        .publishMessageToQuickScore().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(updatedFieldsEntity).build());
    log.info("sending to Quick score" + updatedFieldsEntity.toString());
  }

  public void sendToCompletenessScore(UpdatedFieldsEntity updatedFieldsEntity) {
    customChannels
        .publishMessageToCompletenessScore()
        .send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(updatedFieldsEntity).build());
    log.info("sending to completeness score" + updatedFieldsEntity.toString());
  }

  public void sendToSuitabilityScore(UpdatedFieldsEntity updatedFieldsEntity) {
    customChannels
        .publishMessageToSuitabilityScore()
        .send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(updatedFieldsEntity).build());
    log.info("sending to suitability score" + updatedFieldsEntity.toString());
  }
}
```

**And this is how I am filtering and publishing in different queues :**

```
 @Autowired
  private EventProducer producer;

  public UpdatedFieldsEntity CheckUpdatedKey(UpdatedFieldsEntity updatedFieldsEntity)
      throws RezoomexException {
    logger.info("\n\n Checking UpdateKeys " + updatedFieldsEntity.toString());
    if (updatedFieldsEntity == null) {
      RezoomexException exception = new RezoomexException("update message is null");
      throw exception;
    }
    for (UpdatedFields updatedFields : updatedFieldsEntity.getUpdatedFields()) {
      UpdateKey element = updatedFields.getUpdateKey();
      if (element.toString().equals(TECHNOLOGIES_UNDER_SKILLSET) || element.toString()
          .equals(TOTAL_EXPERIENCE_VALUE)
          || element.toString().equals(TECHNOLOGIES) || element.toString()
          .equals(TOTAL_EXPERIENCE_SUFFIX)) {
        IsThreeScores = true;
      }

    }
    if (IsThreeScores == true) {
      logger.info("\n\n\n publishing message to all Q");
      producer.sendToQuickScore(updatedFieldsEntity);
      producer.sendToSuitabilityScore(updatedFieldsEntity);
      producer.sendToCompletenessScore(updatedFieldsEntity);
      IsThreeScores = false;
    } else {
      logger.info("\n\n\n publishing message to 2 Q");
      producer.sendToSuitabilityScore(updatedFieldsEntity);
      producer.sendToCompletenessScore(updatedFieldsEntity);
    }
    return updatedFieldsEntity;
  }
}
```

The very first time **all queues consumes the message** , but at second time any of the three queues throws exception as :

```
    org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception

Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:154) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you are using same channel for Input and Output (i.e  consuming message and posting message in queue from same channel).
Have different Channel for Consuming for eg:-

```
  @Output("QuickScore")
  MessageChannel publishMessageToQuickScore();

  @Input("Score")
  SubscribableChannel receivedAtQuickScore();
```

In your code change Channel name for @input or @output.